# Can't find imported module "Data.List.HT

Tags: haskell

Hello I am trying to use import Data.List.HT hiding (unzip) for my Haskell program and have gotten the source code for the modules from haskell.org

But now, I don't know how to properly name it and the location to save it in WinHugs.

I am now getting this error message: "**Can't find imported module "Data.List.HT**"

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1):

open terminal and run:

```
cabal install utility-ht
```

or in linux (ubuntu)

```
sudo cabal install utility-ht
```

Also this might not work on Hugs, i only use GHC

Comment: I have done that and install utility-ht is now installed, but still cant't use in both WinHugs and GHC. Any more suggestions?